# did we send you a job offer? asked me the hiring manager

Tags: manager, hiring

Apologies for my English but something really strange happened to me yesterday and I have to share it.

Facts: two weeks ago I had an interview with this company, then never heard from them and assumed I was rejected.
But yesterday I have been contacted by the hiring manager of the company, by e-mail. He basically asked me if his colleague already mentioned me about a job offer they had for me. 
What? I replied that no, I hadn't received any job offer from any of his colleagues but that I would like an update about that. Of course he didn't answer back.

So, what should I do now? call him and ask (I have his phone number) or just wait? I am sure that days will pass without any reply.

I would like some advise from you and to know if anyone had a similar experience or thought it is normal (it doesn't look very normal to me).

Thanks, I appreciate any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: There seems to be a little nuance with the possible duplicate question, namely that in this case the hiring did made a call back mentioning the offer and then it became silent.

Comment: I agree - this question seems to be about a situation which is a little outside the "normal" straightforward hiring process. Considering the delicacy of communications during hiring, I think there's a solid case for this question to remain open and get answers that address the nuance here.

Answer (score 9):

In some cases, the best approach is to just pick up the phone and call. If you already have someone's contact info, and they've tried to get in touch with you, it would hardly be unusual or unexpected to call them back a few times until you get ahold of them.

Many employees try to carefully manage communication with candidates during the hiring process, as a way to ensure a consistent message. Communication is often directed through an internal recruiter or other HR staff. Any time that's the case, you should consider that person your primary contact. But it sounds like, in this case, the hiring manager has reached out directly, which opens the door for you to contact that person back directly. Maybe the HR person is out on PTO, or maybe they left the company - mixups happen, in any case, so calling the person who reached out to you in order to clarify the situation would make sense.

Comment: Anecdotally, I once had an interview, did not hear back, and then was contacted by the hiring manager two weeks later, asking if I'd ever received a job offer from them. Your same situation. It turns out the HR rep who was coordinating hiring had left the company unexpectedly and they truly didn't know if I'd been contacted, or had responded. I ended up accepting the job offer and it was one of my favorite employers.

Answer (score 2):

Do call him and express your confusion. If it turns out to be nothing the call did not hurt your job opportunity and if it turns out they want to hire you, you already have shown a proactive attitude and you get the contract.

Besides that, making the call makes an end about the uncertainty you are feeling now.